# Alias in bash_profile not working after MacOS Catalina upgrade

Tags: bash, macos, alias, macos-catalina

I just upgraded to macOS Catalina (10.15.2) from macOS Mojave. I have used aliases in my ~/.bash_profile and it stopped working after Catalina upgrade.

```
alias mci='mvn clean install'
alias mcit='mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true'
alias mcid='mvn clean install -Dmaven.surefire.debug'
```

What should I do?

Comment: I tried sourcing .bash_profile but it didn't work. Normally when I type the alias halfway and press TAB key it will auto suggest/complete the alias in my terminal. This autocomplete also stopped working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What kind of shell are you using? bash? zsh?

Have you changed anything else in your:

.profile
.bash_profile
.bashrc

If you could add your files here maybe there is a "bug" in the beginning for the files?

Seems catalina has changed the default shell to zsh. So maybe moving your
.bashrc is now .zshrc and .bash_profile is now .zprofile will fix this.

Comment: I have not changed anything. I have nearly 20+ aliases on my `.bash_profile` and all of them were working until the Catalina upgrade.
Let me try `.bash_profile -> .zprofile`

Comment: you should also consider using https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh

Comment: It worked! Thanks @Steffen. 
I tried sourcing the file using >`. ~/.zprofile` and it didn't work as before. Then I sourced using > `souce ~/.zprofile`. It worked!

Comment: ```echo $0```

will tell which shell is used so you are working on the corret files

Comment: `echo $0 -> -bash`

Answer (score 0):

and to go back to bash instead

you can list the shells

```
 cat /etc/shells
```

in the terminal, to update your account to use bash run chsh -s /bin/bash.  enter password if need be and shut it down and re-open